# does zend/php cache hashcodes for functions somewhere in execute data?

Tags: c, php-internals

edit:  to be clear,  I want to identify & track functions called without incurring the cost and ambiguity of hashing on the string of class.function. I was hoping php kept some internal hashes.

I'm working on an extension and I'd like a reliable way of getting a hash code for a particular `zend_execute_data->zend_function`, without the overhead of calling some hash function on the function name (which would result in collisions anyway with overloaded functions).

_zend_execute_data.opline has a field called "extended_value" that looks like it gets set with the value of zend_hash_function against something in op1, but only if op2 is a constant.

```
if (opline->op2.op_type == IS_CONST) {
    ...
    opline->extended_value = zend_hash_func(Z_STRVAL(opline->op1.u.constant), Z_STRLEN(opline->op1.u.constant) + 1);
```

I'm not sure what op2 type IS_CONST means and I'm not sure if this would be reliable or not.  And I'm not sure if this hashcode is for the function definition, or an particular instance on a class.

edit:  I'm guessing IS_CONST means the function is not a member of an object instance.

Anything else that could be used as a hash code proxy for the execute_data->zend_function?

Comment: a) Your code sample looks like PHP 5.3 code - do you really want to target such an ancient version for an *extension*? b) It's not clear at which point you want to get the hash. A custom opcode handler? If so, for which opcode?

Comment: @NikiC I want to identify & track functions called without incurring the cost and ambiguity of hashing on the string of class.function.  I was hoping php kept some internal hashes.  As far as 5.3 - this is legacy code and I need it to work on 5.3 and 5.4 ... I was starting with 5.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple approach is the use the pointer of the `zend_function *` itself to index into a hashtable. I.e. use `(unsigned long) (uintptr_t) func` as the index.

There is one caveat with this approach: While functions/methods *usually* have a unique `zend_function *` during the lifetime of the script, there are some cases (like `__call` magic) where a temporary `zend_function *` structure is allocated. In these cases the `ZEND_ACC_CALL_VIA_HANDLER` flag will be set on the function. If you want to support these cases as well, you'll have to use a separate mechanism for them.

Comment: I need something that is valid for the life of the php/apache process, not the life of the script.  I did try using the pointer as a hash code and it changes for every request.

Comment: Yes, it can change between requests. If you can't use this, then you're out of luck. There is no integral value uniquely identifying the class/method combination.